# Selenium |Maven |Failure trace|Java.lang.NullpointerException| after 1st testcase passed

Tags: java, selenium, maven, exception, test-runner

public class LoginStepDefinitions
{
WebDriver driver;

```
@Given("^User is already on login page$")
public void User_is_already_on_login_page() throws InterruptedException  
{
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions=new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setBinary("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:/selenium/chrome driver/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    
}
    
@When("^title of the page is Flipkart$")
public void Title_of_the_page_is_Flipkart()
{

try 
{
    String title=null;
    title=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);
    Assert.assertEquals("Online Shopping Site for Mobiles, Electronics, Furniture, Grocery, Lifestyle, Books &amp; More. Best Offers!",title);
}
catch (WebDriverException e)
{   
System.out.println("excepion here");
}
}
```

---

getting java lang null point exception after passing the 1st testcase.

Comment: `driver` variable could be null, that's why?

Answer (score 0):

Cause instance of driver is available only for first test method which is `User_is_already_on_login_page`

**3 things** you can do to **fix this** :

1. You can create an instance once and use it in different test cases.
2. You can create a common method for object instantiation and call that method whenever you need driver object.
3. Make use of static. (Make webDriver as static while creating the object)

**Implementation :**

if you do this `static WebDriver driver;` instead of `WebDriver driver` - Your second test method should run.

let me know if you are interested for other two implementation

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**: You declared a instance variable `WebDriver driver` but you didn't assign any object to this variable.

**Solution**: In method `public void User_is_already_on_login_page()`:

Change

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

to

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```